# How to display errors on the html page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I implemented a login form using Google Script with html template. I am fetching data from an URL and if fetching succeed then the `try` block is evaluated, else if the fetch fails the `catch` returns error code 500.

Basically I want to add an error message to the html page if the `urlResponse` return an error because the `username` and `password` are wrong.

Example: I if enter wrong `username` and `password` on the login input fields an error message should appear at the top of the page inside the `error` div.

I am new with google script and I am open to any solutions for solving this...

This is my code:

HTML:

```
  <body>
    <div class="error"></div>
    <form>
        <fieldset class='login'>
            <div class="required">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="input-text" size="10" maxlength="50" value="my.name@address.com" />
            </div>

            <div class="required">
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="input-password" size="10" maxlength="15" value="some-password" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="Login" name='Submit' class='btn'/>
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#submit-btn').click(function() {
          google.script.run
            .login({
               user: $('#username').val(),
               pass: $('#password').val()
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
```

GS:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('login')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('Title')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function login(data){
  Logger.log(data);
  var endpoint = 'login';
  var url = 'https://example.com/api/'+endpoint;
  var payload = {
    'username' : data.user,
    'password' : data.pass,
  }
  var headers = {
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'Accept':'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Cookie':'...',
  }
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : headers,
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload),
  };
  try {
    var urlResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(urlResponse)
    Logger.log(urlResponse.getResponseCode());
  }
  catch(e) {
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not for tags into titles. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by adding .withFailureHandler() function as follows:

```
function onFailure(error) {
  $('.alert').show();
  var div = document.getElementById('error');
  div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + "Wrong username or password";
}
$('#submit-btn').click(function() {
  google.script.run
    .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
    .login({
       user: $('#username').val(),
       pass: $('#password').val()
    });
});
```